# Why is my row of information being moved to the last row in another spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

I have a spreadsheet, and im using app script to move a row of data from one spreadsheet to another when a check box is clicked, however when I click the check box, it moves everything over but to the very last row in the spreadsheet. How can I have the script move the information to the first open row on the target spreadsheet?

```
function onEdit(event) {
  // assumes source data in sheet named Needed
  // target sheet of move to named Acquired
  // test column with yes/no is col 4 or D
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "To Do" && r.getColumn() == 1 && r.getValue() == true) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Q3 Projects");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to put the values to the 1st empty row of the column "A" in the sheet `Q3 Projects`.

In order to achieve your goal, I would like to propose the following patterns.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, the 1st empty row is retrieved with `getNextDataCell`.

#### From:

```
var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
```

#### To:

```
var target = targetSheet.getRange("A1").getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN);
```

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, the 1st empty row is retrieved with the loop.

#### From:

```
var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
```

#### To:

```
var target;
if (targetSheet.getLastRow() == 0) {
  target = targetSheet.getRange(1, 1);
} else {
  var dataRange = targetSheet.getDataRange();
  for (var i = dataRange.getRow() + dataRange.getNumRows() - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
    if (!dataRange.getCell(i, 1).isBlank()) {
      target = targetSheet.getRange(i + 1, 1);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

### References:

- [getNextDataCell(direction)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getnextdatacelldirection)
- [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow)
- [getDataRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange)
- [Loops and iteration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration)

Comment: Thanks for your time! I tried each option above and its still moving the data to the very last row in "Q3 Projects"  spreadsheet. right now I have 2 lines filled in Q3 projects, so Im trying to have the line moved from "To Do" sheet to the 3rd line in Q3 projects since its the first available spot. Once again, I really appreciate you taking time out of your day to help me with this!

Comment: @dreamchaser1024 Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. So in order to correctly understand about your current situation, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet including the script for replicating your current issue? By this, I would like to confirm it. When you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.